# Error using elastic database transaction with sql azure

Tags: azure, transactions, azure-sql-database, msdtc

I have 2 SQL Azure DB's (V12) within a single server and wants the transaction to be atomic. Trying to do what is mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/elastic-database-transactions-with-azure-sql-database/).

I get below exception while trying to wrap the transactions in a single transaction scope. The project targets .net version 4.6. 
What am I missing here?

[image]

Error message (in case image doesn't appear on your end): "The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again. Error code 8510.
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded."

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste the exception as text,images are blocked in some domains

Comment: Done. Added error message text in the question.

Comment: Check out this link ,old but applicable may be:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307802

Comment: Thanks but - this is for SQL Server (does the same apply to SQL Azure since it doesn't support MSDTC?), and second, I don't see the solution mentioned in the link for the issue?!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that you are running with .NET 4.6.1? You need 4.6.1 or later and the exceptions looks like you are running on an earlier .NET version than that.

Thanks,
Torsten

Comment: I am also seeing this error, and I also am definitely running code using .NET 4.6.1.  It's only happening with one particular database.

Comment: It's a  consistently reproducible error if I perform a Point-in-Time restore, then try to perform a multi-database transaction that includes the database which was created as a result of the Point-in-Time restore operation.

Comment: It sounds like it's only happening for one of your databases. I'd love to take a closer look at the server running that database. Can you reply offline to me at torsteng(at)Microsoft(dot)com with the server name and database name for that database? Thanks!